# JMeter & Salesforce : Facing an error as 'Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page. Attempt to de-reference a null object'

Tags: performance, scripting, jmeter, salesforce

I am creating script in JMeter for a Salesforce application but I am Facing an error as

```
Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page. Attempt to de-reference a null object' for one of my POST request. 
Response code received is 500 with message 'Server Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) stands for **Internal Server Error**, you should look into your server logs in order to get to the bottom of the issue.

If you don't have access to your application logs - you can perform some client-side troubleshooting, the common way is to capture the request which is being sent by JMeter and the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare them. The requests should look **exactly the same** (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter))

You should pay attention not only to the request body, but also [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (including [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)) as everything matters.

You might also want to check out [JMeter – Logging Into Salesforce for Automated Testing](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2017/06/29/jmeter-logging-salesforce/) article